# Not able to execute api call for delete through JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a delete API http request in Jmeter which is like "serverName/ApplName/api/deleteDataset/{datasetId}"

In the header i have added the below information:
[image: Header Information]

But strangely this api is failing with the below error:

Response code:400
Response message:Bad Request

Please note when i am trying the same API in postmen it is passing without any error. In fact i did not have to pass any header information apart from the access token.
I have tried removing the extra header information(accept,content-type) too from JMeter but that also did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

If your request works fine in Postman the easiest way of replicating it in JMeter would be just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. [Import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/), this way JMeter will be able to intercept and record [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTPS) requests

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/) so the request to API would go through JMeter

   [image]
4. Run your request in Postman
5. JMeter will generate HTTP Request Sampler and HTTP Header Manager
6. [Correlate](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter) bearer token and replace hard-coded value with the appropriate [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
7. You should be able to run the request successfully now

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thanks for your response. I followed the steps that you suggested but got the same result. So when i tried to run the delete api from Postmen it gave me same "Bad request" response while running through JMeter test script recorder. In fact when i tried the same action from Application UI in chrome browser while recording users actions through JMeter test script recorder i got the same issue of "Bad request" as an error message. So clearly this issue is JMeter specific. What can be the possible reason?